Surface plasmon polariton filling the gaps
Why does the angle of incidence on a DPS(positive electric permeabillity and magnetic susceptibillity)material and a SNG(1 of $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ positive)material have to be close to 90 degrees to create a surface plasmon polariton?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
